# Orbital motion described from an external frame of reference

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics, reference-frames, orbital-motion, galilean-relativity

I am working on proyect where I have to simulate a rocket mission to Mars, and I am having some trouble with it so I wanted to check if my math is ok.

The frame of reference I am using to describe the motion of the rocket is centerend in the Sun, and I am using polar coordinates. I want to describe the velocity of the rocket orbiting around Mars, which if preaty straightforward in Mars coordinates:

The velocity in Mars' polar coordinates would be:

$\omega' = \dfrac{v_{orbital}}{r'}$

$v_{r}' = 0$

Which are the angular and radial velocity respectively, where I am using " ' " to denote Mars' frame of reference.

What I want is to describe it in terms of Sun's frame of reference. Asuming that Mars is orbiting the Sun in a circular orbit with constant angular velocity $\omega_M$, I obtained the following expressions:

$\omega = \frac{1}{r}\left[ D_{SM}\cos(\theta-\omega_Mt)\pm v_{orbital}\cos(\theta-\theta')\right] $

$v_r = D_{SM}\sin(\theta-\omega_Mt)\pm v_{orbital}\sin(\theta-\theta')$

The $\pm$ is for a counter clockwise or clockwise rotation, and "$D_{SM}$" means Sun-Mars distance.

Are these expressions wright? If they are it means that my problem has to do with the program and not with the math.

Thank you!
I hope someone coud help me.